# Prove that the kernel is a principal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, ring-homomorphism

> Is the kernel of $\mathbb Z [x]\to \mathbb R, x\mapsto 1/2+\sqrt{2}$ a principal ideal?

I proved that $(4x^2-4x-7)$ is a subset of the kernel. Now I need to prove that everything in the kernel lies in this ideal. If the polynomial that generates the ideal were monic, I would be able to write $$f(x)=(4x^2-4x-7)q(x)+(ax+b)$$

where $f$ is an arbitrary element of the kernel, and then it would follow that $a$ and $b$ must be zero. But what to do in this case when the leading coefficient isn't 1?

This exercise is given after the chapter on primitive polynomials and stuff like that, but I don't know what exactly to apply and how. I can go to $\mathbb Q[x]$ and do division with remainder there. But then what?

Comment: Well, then the kernel of the $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ map must be equal to the intersection of the kernel of the $\mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ map with $\mathbb{Z}[x]$...

Comment: @DanielSchepler So $(4x^2-4x-7)$ is the kernel of $\mathbb Q[x]\to\mathbb R$, and since that ideal lies in $\mathbb Z[x]$, it's also equal to the kernel of the original map? And I don't need to use stuff like Gauss' lemma or the notion of primitive polynomial?

Comment: Well, that's the basic idea but with a couple minor issues in the execution.  For example, the ideal $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ generated by $4x^2 - 4x - 7$ is not strictly speaking contained in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  There's also a minor issue of: what if you tried making the same argument with $(8x^2 - 8x - 14)$ for example?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Regarding the first point: oh, right, but the intersection of the ideal generated by $4x^2-4x-7$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$ with $\mathbb Z[x]$ is the ideal generated by $4x^2-4x-7$ in $\mathbb Z [x]$. Since the former ideal is the kernel of the "rational" map, it follows from your first comment that $(4x^2-4x-7)\subset \mathbb Z[x]$ is the kernel of the "integer" map. Or does this argument still have minor issues? For the second point: hmm, we would just execute the same division with remainder in $\mathbb Q[x]$?..